# How to pass return value of hook in useEffect dependency array?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I need to use history in isLogin function but according to React guidelines, we should not use hooks inside hooks. If I pass history in the useCallback dependency array, it tells me to memoize the 'history' value. Again, it will be the nesting of hooks.

```
  const [values, setValues] = useState(inititalValues);
  const history = new useHistory();

  const isLogin = useCallback(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      history.push("/");
      toast.error("Please Login");
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    isLogin();
  }, [isLogin]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, a couple of details:

1. You shouldn't call the `useHistory()` with `new`.
2. `history` doesn't change, between calls, so you can essentially use it in the dependency:

```js
  const [values, setValues] = useState(inititalValues);
  const history = useHistory(); // no 'new' keyword

  // The following code will only happen once when the component is "mounted":
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!localStorage.getItem("token")) {
      history.push("/");
      toast.error("Please Login");
    }
  }, [history]);
```